# Is there a way to assert if a span element is bold?

Tags: cypress

I have an span that once it is edited, it needs to turn bold. It has the class .edited on it. I could check that class is there, but I also want to check that the element is actually bold. the .edited class has css on it that changes the font-weight to bold. Is this possible?

Comment: That's not generally the type of thing you'd check with automated E2E tests.

Comment: The requirements are it has to be bold when edited, so I don't want to manually check it every time we go to prod. So i need to write an automatic test for it.. What would you suggest? There seems to be a way according to my google search, I might have an answer soon.

Comment: Testing that the `edited` class gets applied is fine, what specific styling outcome that means doesn't need to be exhaustively tested at this level and may change over time anyway. It's worth understanding *why* that's the requirement, too.

Comment: the issue I have with just checking for the class is some developer could change the  sass code and remove the bold. The label is in a grid and it signifies to the user that they changed this number from what it originally was.  If I can easily test this quickly I think it will be worth it. the risk is someone changes the sass code and does not realize that element must be bold. I can see your point of the risk being small, might not be worth it, but the answer I put satisfies me for now, except for the 400 text instead of bold.

Comment: Why *would* someone change that, unless it was because the specific styling was *supposed* to be changed? (That's rhetorical, just something to think about.) If you can't rely on your colleagues not to randomly change stylesheets, you have deeper problems than E2E testing is designed to solve. Note also that a change to the styling for what "edited" means doesn't actually prevent your users from achieving their outcomes.

Comment: I wish I knew the why? but it happens. People leave the team. Projects get passed around. Someone changes a style not knowing it cascades. We surely have deeper problems, but this test took less time to write than the comments I have written thus far. So I can live with it. I try to use a risk based approach and this is one I could let go. The risk is VERY SMALL, if someone does change the sass code and it is no longer bold, the app will still work. So I can surely see your point. My question is not should we do, but it is possible.

Comment: Sometimes there's confusion between unit tests (which generally test logic) and e2e tests (where the responsibility is to ensure UX). This is a valid thing to test.

Comment: Style !== UX. E2E tests are for *behaviour*, showing that all parts of the system work correctly together. There are some ways of testing that you get pixel-perfect outputs, but they tend to be very flaky. Don't test styling.

Comment: Let us agree to disagree, if the boss says they want it tested. It gets tested. This is not a conversation about should we, this is conversation is how do we. Let this rest..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I came up with this, which has the quirk of using 700: instead of bold

```
cy.get('#period_1').should(($labels)=>{
  expect($labels).to.have.css('font-weight','700');
})
```

I do not like this because chrome must be putting 700 instead of the string 'bold'. I will see if there is a better way.

this led me to this answer https://gitter.im/cypress-io/cypress/archives/2017/11/02

Comment: You might be doing this already (please show the complete test) - I would be checking the before and after `font-weight` to see if it increases. Too pedantic?

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically [a font-weight of 700 is bold](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#syntax). But I would suggest that a higher value is still bold (just even more so).

In `support/commands.ts`:

```
declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            isBold(): Chainable;
        }
    }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('isBold', { prevSubject: true }, (subject) => {
    return cy
        .wrap(subject)
        .should('have.css', 'font-weight')
        .then((fontWeight) => +fontWeight) // string to number
        .and('be.gte', 700); // gte = greater or equal
});
```

Usage example:

```
cy.get('.foo').isBold();
```